# Cant get data by curl on server

Tags: php, curl

I can't get content site:pws0.rai.ir when I run my code on server(show Request Timeout) but when I run on localhost, my code is working.
please help me.

```
curl_setopt($ch2,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Accept: */*',
'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
'Accept-Language: fa-IR,fa;q=0.9,en-GB;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6',
'Cache-Control: no-cache',
'Connection: keep-alive',
'Content-Length: 135',
'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
'Cookie: __RequestVerificationToken=5LVx8SblZ5tsuUuhWXAMGyX-F25RVQO-QcuJUMx9XPPKIy7JT4jAWEeOV9NmaQqNl6WVVNJGAP5e1RUFhkMxwbeqF0GXSbmuu2Iv36CKLIM1',
'Host: pws0.rai.ir',
'Pragma: no-cache',
'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36'));
curl_setopt($ch2,CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch2,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'__RequestVerificationToken=jY623kZ6xToDB2Z4z9v0dPoZBUd4-fExXx_fmNyQmdLx6FKvCj1jd_mAWDZXKReu8bm2B2lTvMy8FIBfh_UB6h84kexu5_F43zLDa7bXacM1');
$result2=curl_exec($ch2);
echo $result2;
```

Comment: Show us your code please. :)

Comment: Since it works from your localhost but not the server, the server may be filtering outgoing connections for security. Check with your server administrator to find out if this is the case.

Comment: Your server firewall blocks a needed port. I would open a support ticket and ask your admin for help.

Comment: I can get contents from another site but can't get content from this site.